# Contagem de dados com Python

Tags: python, lista, pandas, count

Bom dia pessoal!

Estou manipulando uma base, e estou tentando criar uma coluna com a quantidade de vezes que uma pessoa aparece em uma determinada coluna.

```
dados = ['laranja', 'banana', 'maçã', 'morango', 'uva', 'pera', 'maçã', 'limão', 'banana', 'laranja']
valores = []
repetidos = set()

for dado in dados:
    if dado not in valores:
        valores.append(1)
    else:
        repetidos.add(1++1)
print(f'Valores = {valores}')
print(f'Repetidos = {repetidos}')
```

Preciso de um resultado parecido com o exemplo abaixo:

dados = ['laranja', 'banana', 'maçã', 'morango', 'uva', 'pera', 'maçã', 'limão', 'banana', 'laranja']

valores = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '2', '2']

Preciso da informação, se é a primeira vez que apareceu = 1, apareceu novamente = 2 ...

Agradeço pela atenção e pela ajudar!

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO! Tente fazer uma pergunta mais direcionada, explique melhor o que você tentou e onde exatamente que surgiu o problema, para facilitar o trabalho de quem for responder. Perguntas muito gerais do tipo "como resolver esse enunciado?" ou "como eu melhoro esse código?" não são boas perguntas. De qualquer forma, veja se a minha resposta de ajudou.

Comment: Este exemplo que você apresentou é para que possamos replicar? Pergunto isso, pois sua pergunta menciona _"criar uma coluna com a quantidade de vezes que uma pessoa aparece em uma determinada coluna"_ . Onde estaria `pessoa`. Outra coisa: você colocou a _tag_ `pandas`. Você teria seus dados em um _dataframe_?

Answer (score 0):

Como você precisa saber quantas vezes um item apareceu no passado, é necessário um dicionário para marcar essa informação.

Então, para cada elemento de `dados`, incrementamos a entrada associada nesse dicionário, e, após essa conta, adicionamos o resultado em `valores`.

```
dados = ['laranja', 'banana', 'maçã', 'morango', 'uva', 'pera', 'maçã', 'limão', 'banana', 'laranja', 'laranja', 'laranja', 'laranja']
frequencia = {}
valores = []

for dado in dados:
    frequencia[dado] = frequencia.get(dado, 0) + 1
    valores.append(frequencia[dado])
  
print(f'Valores = {valores}')
```

Answer (score -1):

Essa resposta é a mesma que acima, mas mais breve:

```
frequencias = {valor: dados.count(valor) for valor in set(dados)}

# Vendo o dicionário
for valor, frequencia in frequencias.items():
    print(f"{valor}: {frequencia}")
```